# Why DynamoDB will not accept empty map via PHP api?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I try to put item to my DynamoDB using Amazons PHP api however I get

> Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException [ 0 ]: Start of list found
>   where not expected

where that very same json can be put via Amazon web interface.

Json:

```
{"Url":"test","Referers":{}}
```

PHP array dump as Marshaled by Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler

```
array (size=2)
  'Url' => 
   array (size=1)
     'S' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'Referers' => 
    array (size=1)
      'M' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

I tried with empty list and it seems that only empty map objects cause problem. Why? Still one can do this with their web interface. Is there any workaround or am I doing something wrong?

My code:

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(/*settings*/);
$marshaler = new Marshaler();

$response = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'StatisticsVisits', 
    'Item' => $marshaler->marshalJson('{"Url":"test","Referers":{}}')
));
```

Comment: Empty lists ad Empty maps are the same thing in PHP. Can we see the code you are doing to input the data and marshal it? I might be able to make a suggestion.

Comment: I added my code it's really short. When I change empty map { } to empty list [ ] it works however it makes nothing good for me as I obviously can't add any key/value pairs to it later.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Let's continue the discussion here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=181871